# how to add download button to export data table in bokeh?

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I came across the demo below to show how to download datatable on bokeh but could not find relevant info about how to implement. I have a bokeh application with data table as well and want to add download button for use to download and play around with the data.

Any help is appreciated!

https://demo.bokeh.org/export_csv

Comment: You can find the source code here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/export_csv

Comment: @EugenePakhomov, thanks a lot it works like a charm!